# What would you call a group of Witchers?

Tags: the-witcher

What is the collective noun for a group of Witchers?

A *murder* of Witchers might work, because a group of crows is also called a murder. It is both sinister and links with crows' symbolism as an omen of doom yet wise. It is also slightly insulting, which reflect how the Witchers are generally viewed.

Comment: I asked a friend who's read all the novels in the original Polish, and she tells me that there's no such term; one would just refer to them as "a group of Witchers". Of course, I can't prove a negative, but I assume she'd be aware of it if such a term existed.

Comment: To my knowledge, the only 'grouping' term normally used for Witchers is a School...and that's a specific grouping based on where they were trained, not a generic one that could apply to any random group of them. In fact, I suspect there was never reason to come up with a name for a group of Witchers because when they were together...it was generally back with others of their school (and no one really saw them then), otherwise, Witchers were generally solitary while they were on The Path. Outside of their strongholds, the most Witchers we ever see in one place are two of them.

Comment: @guildsbounty: This sounds like the answer that the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I put this as a comment, I may as well put it down here as an answer with a bit of expansion.

There is no canonical term for a random grouping of Witchers.

The one term we have heard used of 'groups' of Witchers is a School. But the School is a term directly tied to the location, tradition, and methods of their training. Geralt is of the Wolf-School, and we've heard of or met Witchers from the Cat, Griffon, Bear, Manticore, and Viper schools.

However, as I said, this is a specific term for a training tradition of Witchers, not a generic term for an ad-hoc group of them.

While this is not specifically supported by the books, there is a very good reason, in-universe, as to why there is no such term. You don't see Witchers in groups. When Witchers are on The Path, they are solitary. They run into one another on occasion, work together sometimes, but eventually split off and go their separate ways. While on The Path, the largest number of Witchers we have ever seen traveling together is 3...and this was temporary, not something intended to last throughout the entire season they were out and about. The only time they really gather up is during the Winter, when they return to their School to wait out the snows.

To give a real-life example, there is no term for a group of Honey Badgers, because they are generally solitary creatures...thus there is no reason to give a name to something which does not exist. So, like the Honey Badger (in more ways than just this), there is no term for a group of Witchers.

Comment: "*The hall was enormous, and flooded with light from a huge hearth roaring with flames which were being sucked up into the heart of the chimney. The centre of the hall was taken up by an enormous, heavy table. At least ten people could sit around that table. There were three. Three humans. Three witchers, Ciri corrected herself. She saw nothing but their silhouettes against the fire in the hearth.*" - The Malady and Other Stories...

Comment: Ah, thank you for the correction, I'll update the answer. Actually...where was that scene taking place? If it was at Kaer Morhen, then my original answer is still correct as that is them Wintering...not out on The Path.

Comment: Dunno. I just happen to have a copy of the e-book in my collection. I did a quick search to see if I could find an answer to the question, but alas none was forthcoming.